# how select a table value with different table with where clause in there

Tags: php, mysql

i want to ask about php queries. i want to select under select a data with a where clause condition in there. in the 1st queries i have select all data in table `wjm` with where condition `(date between $a and $b) and kode=$c and user='Borongan'`. nah in that queries i get all of my data. my problem is i want to change the data `kode` that i get from `wjm` into `name` in my data `material`. for change that i need a where clause again with checking the `kode` value from data that i get from `wjm` then check into table `material` with condition `select nama from where kode='the code that i get from wjm'`

the query that i have made for the `wjm table is like this`

`SELECT * 
 FROM wjm 
 WHERE (date BETWEEN '$date_awal' and '$date_akhir') 
       AND kode ='$kode' 
       AND uses='Borongan' 
 ORDER by no asc`

and i want to make a select again inside them with the kode that i have got from that query. the queries that i want to make like this

`SELECT nama 
 FROM material 
 where kode='the code that i got from wjm'`

can i do something like that. i mean its posible to do something like that?

Comment: What you ask is not clear. You *got* no `kode` from wjm: rather, the `kode` is in the query and you put it in there as a parameter, `$code`. *How*, exactly, are you selecting from `material`?

Comment: Please clarify!

Comment: Please post your table definitions. I think you might be looking for a `JOIN`. With a join you can select data from two or more tables with only one query.

Comment: Oh, and please educate yourself about SQL injections and parameterized queries. Your code looks like it is vulnerable.

Comment: @MrProPop let me explain it..
in my queries above. i have queries that i use for selecting all data in my `wjm` table. that table contain a column `kode`. after i get all data from that.
i want to get `name` from my table `material` with the data `kode` that i got from selection in `wjm` table. "i want to get `name` from my table `material` i mean do something like change the value of `kode` into `name` from `material`"

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because user data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Comment: @tadman thx for that. i will try to change the queries